# updating database base on option selection

Tags: php, html-select, forms

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.I'm new in php so can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong??

This is the form:

```
<center><br/><h2>Update Form</h2></center>
<div id="login">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h3>Update Form</h3></legend>
<h4 style="color:pink;"><?php global $nam; echo $nam;?> </h4> 
<?php global $error; echo $error;?>                  
        <!-- the login form-->
<form action='login_reg_action.php' method='post' id='myform'>
            <div class="login">
            <table width="400px">

<tr>
<td><label>Username</label></td>
<td colspan="2"><span class="style8">
 <div align="center">
      <?php
      include 'connection.php';
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM login_1 ORDER BY username';
      $sele=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      ?>
      <select name="login_id" style="width:250px; height:34px; border:1px solid #336666;">
        <option required="required" value="000" > [SELECT STUDENT]</option>
        <?php
       while($numu=mysqli_fetch_array($sele))
       {
      ?>
        <option required="required" value="<?php echo $numu['login_id'];?> ">  <?php echo $numu["login_id"];echo'  -  ';echo $numu["username"] ?>   </option>
        <?php
      }
      ?>
      </select>
      </label>
      </div>
  </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><label>Rank</label></td>
 <td><select name="rank" id="rank" style="width:250px; height:34px; border:1px solid #336666;">
 <option value="000">Choose user rank</option>
 <option value="student">Student</option>
 <option value="candidate">Candidate</option>
 <option value="administrator">Administrator</option>
 </select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" style="width:100px; height:34px; border:1px solid #336666; border-radius:4px;"></td></tr>
             </table>
            </div>
 </form>
```

and this the form action. This form will process any input data in the first form:

```
 <?php

 $servername="localhost";
 $username="root";
 $password="";
 $dbname="o-voting_db";
 //Create connection
 $con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);


 $name      = $_POST['login_id'];
 $rank      = $_POST['rank'];



 if(!$name || !$rank){
 $error="Please fill empty fields";
 include"login_reg.php";
 exit();
 }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$sql1="UPDATE login_1 SET rank='$rank' WHERE username='$name'";


  // if($rank=='candidate'){
   //include 'reg_cand.php';
   //}

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1)or die(mysqli_error($sql1));

 if(!$result){
 die("Could not update data: " .mysqli_error($con));
  }
 else{
 $nam="<center><h4><font color='#00FF00'>Successful update,</h4></center>  </font>";
include "login_reg.php";
}
}


?>
```

Comment: Please narrow down your question. What's that you expect and is not happening? Are you getting any errors? Which ones? Where are you running this code? What's your web stack like?

Comment: Try removing required attribute from option tag and adding it to the select tag

Comment: @sal I don't get any error but it's not updating though the message says that it was successfully updated

Comment: @Mals make the check on `$result` stricter, like: `if ($result === False)` and if that does not help yet, I would suggest you insert more checks and tests along the way. See examples under the  [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: @sal also even if  I don't select any data yet in option and click the update button still message that it was successfully update.

Comment: @Mals: looks like you are having very basic problems with database interaction. Please start by making sure you are able to query and print the correct data from the database, then work your way up from there. Once you single out any issues you will get this code working in no time. But DO start simple first.

Comment: Yes I did that already and it's working. but when I'm trying it with that code. I'm having a problem.